# Tweepy throws exception saying "tweepy.error.TweepError: Could not determine file type", when image is a valid format and works when manually tweeted?

Tags: python, exception, tweepy, wikipedia

I'm trying to tweet an image using the tweepy api and for some images it throws:

```
"tweepy.error.TweepError: Could not determine file type"
```

When I tweet the same image through the browser, it works. This only happens for a few images and I can't tell what differentiates them from the ones I can tweet out.

The code I'm using to tweet them out is:

```
media_list = []
response = api.media_upload(imgPath)
media_list.append(response.media_id_string)
api.update_status(output, media_ids=media_list)
```

The Path is the exact path to the downloaded image, it lookes like this:

```
IMAGES/TweetImage.jpg
```

How can I fix this or whats causing it?

Answer (score 0):

With more debugging, I found out that this problem occurs on windows or is MUCH more likely to occur on windows. I moved my code to a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian OS) and every image is tweeting. I have not found a solution to this on windows, but I suspect it relates to how images are saved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue recently and it was probably due to imgur scrubbing Meta data from the pictures. I used a different image hosting service and didn't have any issues.